# XSLT boolean value

Tags: xslt, boolean

I tried searching for my issue on here and was unsuccessful.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$all_events[g:active = 1]">
        <xsl:sort select="g:event_date" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:variable name="fileName"><xsl:value-of select="fn:replaceAll(string(@alf:file_name), '.xml', '.html')"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="fileURL"><xsl:value-of select="concat('/events/', $fileName)" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="fileDate"><xsl:value-of select="g:event_date" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="date"><xsl:value-of select="substring($fileDate, 6, 2)" /></xsl:variable>   
        <li><a href="{$fileURL}"><xsl:value-of select="g:event_title"/></a></li>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </ul><br/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$all_events[g:body/g:current = 1]">
        <xsl:for-each select="g:body">
            <h2 class="normal"><xsl:value-of select="g:sub_title" /></h2>
                <xsl:for-each select="g:paragraphs">
                    <xsl:value-of select="g:paragraph" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
```

I have two for-each statements checking my XSD for a true or false value:

```
<xs:simpleType name="confirm">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean"/>
 </xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="active" type="g:confirm" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="current" type="g:confirm" minOccurs="0"/>
```

The above is not working for me. I've also tried `true()/false()` which seemed to have failed as well.

Am I missing something obvious?

Edit:
The boolean values are checkboxes in Alfresco CMS, so I can't simply check it's existence but rather whether it's true or false.

```
<xs:simpleType name="confirm">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:boolean"/>
 </xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="content">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="page_title" type="xs:normalizedString"  minOccurs = "0">
                <xs:annotation> 
                    <xs:appinfo> 
                        <alf:appearance>title</alf:appearance> 
                    </xs:appinfo> 
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="event_title" type="xs:normalizedString"  minOccurs = "0">
                <xs:annotation> 
                    <xs:appinfo> 
                        <alf:appearance>title</alf:appearance> 
                    </xs:appinfo> 
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="active" type="g:confirm" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="event_date" type="xs:date" />
            <xs:element name="body" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="sub_title" type="xs:normalizedString"  minOccurs = "0">
                            <xs:annotation> 
                                <xs:appinfo> 
                                    <alf:appearance>title</alf:appearance> 
                                </xs:appinfo> 
                            </xs:annotation>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="current" type="g:confirm" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="paragraphs" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="paragraph" type="xs:string"  minOccurs = "0">
                                        <xs:annotation> 
                                            <xs:appinfo> 
                                                <alf:appearance>custom</alf:appearance> 
                                            </xs:appinfo> 
                                        </xs:annotation>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare against the values 'true' and 'false' as well as '1' and '0':

```
$all_events[(g:active = 'true') or (g:active = 1)]
```

Because the possible values of an [`xs:boolean`](http://www.ncsconline.org/d_tech/wayfarer1.9/showclass.asp?id=239) element are those four values.

In XPath 2.0 you would be able to cast them using the `boolean()` function. Since that doesn't work for you I'm assuming you're using XPath 1.0.

Comment: So like this `$all_events[boolean(g:active) = 1]` ?

Comment: No. There's no need for any comparisons like that. `$all_events[boolean(g:active)]` will do fine. If you need to compare something, compare to an actual boolean value, like this: `$all_events[boolean(g:active) = true()]`. Again, that is not necessary.

Comment: I believe I have to specify whether it's true or false because now whether the checkbox is checked or not it displays. Event adding `true()` didn't work.

Comment: How about you give me a sample of your source document so I can see for myself what you're working with?

Comment: I added parts from both my XSD and XSLT. They tie in with Alfresco CMS as a Web Form and create checkboxes. Which source document are you referring to?

Comment: Thank you that worked! Thanks for helping me with my previous issue as well. Much appreciated!